# Post request in redux-saga not working, nothing seems to happen

Tags: reactjs, http, redux, redux-saga

I would like to make post request in redux-saga. My code looks like:

```
var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("points", "a,b");
    formdata.append("pid", "someid");
    formdata.append("tions", "cses");
    formdata.append("exp", "cx");
const ans = yield call(fetch,
'http://localhost:8000/api',
{
    method: "POST",
    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Token tokenid',
                "Content-Type": "application/json",},
    body : formdata
});
```

In Postman it is working fine (selected `form-data` in body), but in saga, the POST request is not happening at all.

Please suggest where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your Exceptions on server-side, When you are throwing an error the headers are not set. So what you should do is with CORS Errors only with 400 bad request react fetch request.

Answer (score 0):

**Update** :- The 400 Bad request has gone away after I added `"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` in the headers and changed the body type accordingly

Example :-

```
fetch("api/xxx", {
    body: "email=test@example.com&password=pw",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    },
    method: "post",
}
```